# Distribution function of the linear combination of standardized student-t quantiles

Tags: probability, correlation, normal-distribution

Assume to observe 2 quantiles, x and y, associated with the z% probability. These quantiles are generated by 2 non-independent standardized student-t distributions X and Y.

In case of linear combination of x and y with the Correlation matrix, its distribution function is known?

Can I assume any initial condition on x and y in order to have a known distribution function of the linear combination?

Comment: Could you please describe any kind of experimental setup or procedure that actually *observes* specified quantiles?  How do you know the correlation?  Even when you do, that does not determine the distribution, so what distribution family do you have in mind specifically?

Comment: Thanks whuber. In this procedure, I have a statistical model for quantiles. Furthermore, I am able to assume any distribution family. Sample correlation matrix is given. Honestly, I cannot figure out how to set assumptions in order to have a (generalized) student-t linear combination of standardized student-t quantiles and a given sample correlation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Answers are in McNeil, Frey and Embrechts, "Quantitative Risk Management", Princeton 2005.

Seems that, assuming a student-t multivariate distribution, linear combination of marginals is also standardized student-t.

See also [Linear Combination of multivariate t distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80809/linear-combination-of-multivariate-t-distribution)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you asked: it assumes unstated information.  With the usual multivariate Student t there's really nothing to ask because that family is constructed to have this property.

Comment: IMHO, this do answer the question because I stated was looking for a known distribution function under any reasonable condition (multivariate student-t). Additional details are in my previous comment.

Comment: Please, let me see any other unstated information. Thanks.

Comment: "Non-independent" does not mean "multivariate t."  There are plenty of multivariate distributions with Student t marginals that are not this particular "multivariate t."