# Combining confidence intervals from several regression point estimates

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction

I have 13 point predictions from 13 independent linear regressions, each prediction with a 95% confidence interval.  I want to sum the 13 predictions and calculate the 95%CI for the summed value.  How, or should I, combine the 13 CIs to get the CI for the summed value?

Comment: If the regressions are truly independent, then what use is this?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "point prediction"? I also wonder about your intended meaning of "independent." Most people would understand that as involving independent *datasets*, but it occurs to me that you might intend it in a different sense, such as "regressions independently conducted by 13 different people based on the same data." Please clarify.

Comment: The point estimate is for a future observable, so I have a prediction interval.  The 13 regressions are from 13 independent datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have *predictions* and *prediction intervals* (i.e., for future observables), or *parameter estimates* and *confidence intervals* (i.e., for unobservable model parameters)? No, it won't make a difference for the answer, but if you have your nomenclature correct, it will be easier for you to find help.

Either way, you have a sum of 13 independent $t$ distributed random variables. Unless [you have some specific information on your 13 variables, like common variances](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67623/1352), the sum [does not have a closed form solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10857/1352).

You can either simulate many realizations and look at the empirical distribution of the sums, or (if you have sufficiently high degrees of freedom) approximate your $t$ distributions by independent normals and hope for the best. The sum of independent normals is normal, with mean equal to the sum of the component means (same for variances).

Comment: These are predictions and prediction intervals for a future observable(s). Are you suggesting many simulations of the 13 intervals through random selection from the interval, and then looking at the distribution of simulatio sums?

Comment: Yes! (Using $t$ distributions with appropriate degrees of freedom, of course, not just uniform draws from p% prediction intervals.)

Comment: Ah, this makes sense to me now and will work fine for my needs.  Thanks!