# Distribution of sum of squares of T-distributed random variables

Tags: probability, sums-of-squares

I am looking at the distribution of the sum of squares of T-distributed random variables, with tail exponent $\alpha$. Where X is the r.v., the Fourier transform for $X^2$, $\mathscr{F}(t)$ gives me a solution for the square before the convolution $\mathscr{F}(t)^n$. 
$$\mathscr{F}(t)=\int_0^{\infty } \exp \left(i\, t\, x^2\right)\left(\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +x^2}\right)^{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}} }{\sqrt{\alpha }\ B\left(\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

With $\alpha=3$, the solution is possible but unwieldy and impossible to inverse to do an inverse Fourier for $\mathscr{F}(t)^n$. 
So the question is: has work been done on the distribution of the sample variance or standard deviation of T-distributed random variables?  (It would be to the StudentT what the Chi-square is to the Gaussian).
Thank you.

(Possible Solution) I figured out that $X^2$ is Fisher $F(1,\alpha)$ distributed, hence will look at the sum of Fisher distributed variables.

(Possible Solution) From the Characteristic Functions  the average of $n-$summed $X^2$  has the same first two moments of a $F(n,\alpha)$ distribution when these exist. Hence with u the square root and doing a change of variable inside a probability distribution, the density of the standard deviation of n-sample T variables can be approximated with:
$$g(u)=\frac{2 \alpha ^{\alpha /2} n^{n/2} u^{n-1} \left(\alpha +n u^2\right)^{-\frac{\alpha }{2}-\frac{n}{2}}}{B\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}$$

Comment: $T^2$ is $F$-distributed. The mean and variance of a sum of independent $F(1,\alpha)$-distributed variables is readily derived, but the distribution is not available in closed form. See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/what-is-the-sum-of-squared-t-variates) for some details. You may find the linked paper useful. The characteristic function is also given at the wikipedia page for the F. [The sample variance of t-distributed variables is a rather different question.]

Answer (score 8):

A clarification of your question (there seem to me to be two related, but different, parts): you are looking for (1) distribution of a sum of $n$ *independent* squared $t_{\alpha }$ random variables, and
(2) the *sampling* distribution of the variance (or the related standard deviation) of a random sample drawn from a $t_{\alpha }$ distribution (presumably your reason for asking about (1)).

#### Distribution of Sum of Independent Squared $t_{\alpha }$ Variables

If $T_i\sim t_{\alpha }$ are (independent) random $t$ variables with $\alpha$ d.f., then it is false that $\sum _{i=1}^n T_i^2\sim F(n,\alpha )$ (which is what you seem to be claiming in your second "possible solution"). This is easily verified by considering the first moment of each (the latter's first moment is $n$ times the first's).

The claim in your first "possible solution" is correct: $T_i^2\sim F(1,\alpha)$.  Rather than resorting to characteristic functions, I think this result is more transparent when considering the characterisation of the $t$ distribution as the distribution of the ratio $\frac{Z}{\sqrt{U/\alpha}}$ where $Z$ is a standard normal variable and $U$ is a chi-squared variable with $\alpha$ degrees of freedom, independent of $Z$. The square of this ratio is then the ratio of two independent chi-squared variables scaled by their respective degrees of freedom i.e. $\frac{V/1}{U/\alpha}$ with $V=Z^2$, which is a standard characterisation of an $F(1,\alpha)$ distribution (with numerator d.f. equal to 1 and denominator d.f. equal to $\alpha$).

Considering the note I made on first moments in the first paragraph above, it might seem that a better claim may be that $\sum _{i=1}^n T_i^2\sim n F(n,\alpha )$ [I have slightly abused notation here by using the same expression for the distribution as well as a random variable having that distribution.].  Whilst the first moments match, the second central moments do not (for $\alpha>4$ the variance of the first expression is less than the variance of the latter expression) - so this claim is false too.  [That being said, it is interesting to observe that $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty } \, n F(n,\alpha)= \chi _n^2$, which is the result we expect when summing squared (standard) normal variates.]

#### Sampling Distribution of Variance When Sampling from a $t_{\alpha }$ Distribution

Considering what I have written above, the expression you obtain for "the density of the standard deviation of n-sample T variables" is incorrect.  However, even if the $F(n,\alpha)$ were the correct distribution, the standard deviation is not simply the square root of the sum of squares (as you seem to have used to arrive at your $g(u)$ density).  You would instead be looking for the (scaled) sampling distribution of $\sum _{i=1}^n \left(T_i-\bar{T}\right){}^2=\sum _{i=1}^n T_i^2-n \bar{T}^2$.  In the normal case, the LHS of this expression can be re-written as a sum of squared normal variables (the term inside the square can be re-written as a linear combination of normal variables which is again normally distributed) which leads to the familiar $\chi^2$ distribution. Unfortunately, a linear combination of $t$ variables (even with the same degrees of freedom) is not distributed as $t$, so a similar approach can not be exploited.

Perhaps you should re-consider what it is you wish to demonstrate?  It may be possible to achieve the objective using some simulations, for example.  However, you do indicate an example with $\alpha=3$, a situation where only the first moment of $F(1,\alpha)$ is finite, so simulation won't help with such moment calculations.

Comment: Thanks Mark; indeed the convolution breaks down although the first two moments are preserved. Will try Chi-square and revert.

Comment: I rephrased my question. Or should I post modifications elsewhere on the page?

Comment: Nero -- changes to your question should appear in the question. You can always signal how the question changed in the question if that helps (though keep in mind that the entire edit-history of the question and answers is available if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Hotelling's T-distribution ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling's_T-squared_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution)).  There is relationships with $T^2$ being a $F$-distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties), but I'm not sure this is exactly what you're asking for.