# Sample from sum of squared independent $t_\nu$ distributed variables

Tags: sampling, t-distribution

I would like to specify radius r in a case where: $$\mathbb{P}(Z_1^2 + Z_2^2>r)=a\,,$$ $a$ is known, and $Z_1,Z_2$ are i.i.d $t_\nu$-distributed.

**Question:** Any ideas on how to do this?

**Attempt:** Since this can be really challenging to do analytically, I decided to do it by sampling.

My first thought was to simply draw N random values a from $t_\nu$ distributed variable and then count how many are there that fulfill the $|t_k|\geq r$ condition, then update $r$ until I cross $a$, but I'm not really convinced that this is the correct way. The $\nu$ value doesn't really matter.

I have checked these two posts: [(1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78940/distribution-of-sum-of-squares-of-t-distributed-random-variables) [(2)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/what-is-the-sum-of-squared-t-variates).

**Edit** As was pointed out in the comments by whuber, it may be possible to numerically compute the probability through the integral.

I would also use this solution, but as I understood from the posts linked above, it will be really tricky.

Comment: Your question--which asks to compute the inverse distribution function of a sum of squared t variables--does not seem to agree with the title, which asks to draw a sample.  Could you please edit one (or both) to make them consistent?

Comment: Thank you--the nature of your question is clear now. Would it still be worth pointing out that a numerical evaluation of the integral would be quicker and far more accurate than any amount of sampling?

Comment: I m not sure, i can write down the integral of the $f_{(Z_1^2,Z_2^2)}(z_1,z_2)$ (the pdf) correctly. If you could help me with that, i d appreciate it.

Comment: If that calculation would help you, then please edit your question to mention that.  I'm confident that many community members would know of answers and I believe you're likely to get several different, but good, ones.

Comment: Ι don't really believe that it can be done through the integral though, since you are looking for a very tricky pdf there. So sampling is probably the best solution.

Comment: This PDF is benign!  There isn't anything terribly tricky about it.  There are many ways to perform the computation accurately and fairly quickly.

Comment: Please feel free to propose it!

Comment: Sure: for $\nu=3$ and $r=3.5$, for example, the complementary integral can be found by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate[%28%283^%283%2F2%29+%28x+%2B+3%29^%281%2F2+%28-1+-+3%29%29%29+%283^%283%2F2%29+%283.5+-+x+%2B+3%29^%28+++++1%2F2+%28-1+-+3%29%29%29%29%2F%28%28Sqrt[x]+Beta[1%2F2%2C+3%2F2]%29+%28Sqrt[3.5+-+x]++++++Beta[1%2F2%2C+3%2F2]%29%29%2C+{x%2C+0%2C+3.5}])

Comment: the pdf you must integrate should be the pdf of $Z_1^2 + Z_2^2$ and not the pdf of $Z_1,Z_2$. That's why it is hard.

Comment: The event $\{Z_1^2+Z_2^2\ge r\}$ is also an event for $(Z_1,Z_2)$ so all you need is a pdf on $(Z_1,Z_2)$.